# Как работают указатели в Си?

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Помогите решить эти задания:

> Pointer : Let’s assume the next arrangement was declared. Calculate
>   the final value of the following expression:

2.1. `*(**p+3)`, `*(**p+1)`, `p[0]`, `**(p[1]+1)`, `*(p[1]+1)`

```
 char p[3][2] = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijklm", "nop", "wxyz"};
```

---

2.2. `*text`, `*(text+3)`, `*(text+7)`

```
 char *text;
 char more[] = "Happy Holidays";
 text = &more[4];
```

Comment: Язык С запрещает избыточные инициализаторы в объявлении (с редкими исключениями). Ваше `char p[3][2] = ...` по этой причине не является корректным. Некорректны также большинство выражений в 2.1. Вы, очевидно, что-то неправильно воспроизвели. Может было `char *p[3][2] = ...`?

Comment: Я перепроверил, это дано так. Но все равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Сорри, действительно было char *p[3][2] = ...

Answer (score 1):

Что-то мне слабо верится в

```
char p[3][2] = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijklm", "nop", "wxyz"};
```

Вы точно все переписали как надо? Это у вас массив из 3 строк по 1 символу каждая (+один нулевой символ), а инициализируете вы его пятью строками... Так что на этот вопрос не вижу смысла отвечать, он некорректен. Что-то вы не так переписали.

Во втором случае все просто - `text` - адрес четвертого (считая с 0!) символа, т.е. `y`. Соответственно, `*text == 'y'`.
`text+4` - указатель на 7 символ, соответственно, `*text == 'o'`.
`text+7` - указатель на 11 символ, соответственно, `*text == 'a'`.

И еще - здесь все-таки **ru** SO, так что лучше вопросы задавать по-русски.

**Update**

Раз

```
char * p[3][2] = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijklm", "nop", "wxyz"};
```

То имеем двумерный массив указателей на строки

```
  "abcd", "efgh", 
  "ijklm", "nop", 
  "wxyz",  NULL
```

`*(**p+3)` - `**p` - по сути указатель `p[0][0]` (`*p == p[0]`, `*p[0] == p[0][0]`), так что добавление 3 дает третий (от нуля) символ строки `p[0][0]`, т.е. `d`.

`*(**p+1)` - аналогично, символ `b`

`p[0]` - строка указателей на строки `"abcd", "efgh"`, т.е. по сути адрес первого элемента массива `&p[0][0]`.

`**(p[1]+1)` - `p[1]` - вторая строка массива, значит, `p[1]+1` - указатель на ее второй элемент, `"nop"`. Первое разыменование дает строку, второе - ее первый символ `n`.

`*(p[1]+1)` - на одно разыменование меньше, так что просто указатель на строку `"nop"`.

*"По-моему, так"* (с) Пух

Comment: Извиняюсь, я ошибся было char *p[3][2] = ...

Comment: Тогда смотрите дополненный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Ну, тут спасибо - это стрелочка и птичка слева от вопроса :) Если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый...